# Map 2 list to a function

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Im playing around with `CountryData` and I want to pass it 2 lists as argument, `listCountries = {...}` and `data = {"GDP","ExternalDebt"}`

If I do `CountryData[#, "GDP"]& /@ listCountries` it works well, but I want something like

```
CountryData[#1, #2]& /@ {listCountries,data}
```

I read something about `MapThread` but can make it.

Comment: Just did, it take the first 2 elements of the first list as input of #1 and #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these two lists:

```
listCountries = {
   "Bangladesh",
   "India",
   "Monaco"
   };
data = {
   "GDP",
   "Population",
   "Area"
   };
```

There are two cases: you want the GDP, population and area of each country in the first list. The most elegant solution I can think of is `Outer`:

```
Outer[CountryData, listCountries, data]
```

[image]

The other is that you want the GDP of Bangladesh, the Population of India and the area of Monaco; this can be achieved by either

```
CountryData @@ # & /@ Thread@{listCountries, data}
```

[image]

or

```
MapThread[CountryData, {listCountries, data}]
```

Comment: Yes!, that would do. That was more than awesome, I love this forum and how you people gave answers by teaching.Thank you guys!

Comment: @Öskå hey, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? Using `Map` twice feels like the most intuitive approach to me.

```
listCountries = {"United States", "Mexico", "Canada"};
data = {"GDP", "ExternalDebt"};
Function[{country}, CountryData[country, #] & /@ data] /@ listCountries
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to display the country next to its data, just modify your Function to include that information.

```
listCountries = {"United States", "Mexico", "Canada"};
data = {"GDP", "ExternalDebt"};
Function[{country}, Prepend[CountryData[country, #] & /@ data, 
   country]] /@ listCountries
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can do `Outer[{#1, CountryData[#1, #2]} &, listCountries, data]` for the second bit. `Outer` is very flexible and well worth understanding.

Comment: @acl Great tip! Thank you.